# Can't add expansion libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, apk-expansion-files

I'm following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing) for working with expansion files in Android, but I can't even get the modules set up. When I make a new module and try to import the library as described in item 5 it clears out the path I entered. So I tried to use the terminal commands and there were all kinds of problems with those.

First I tried

```
android update project --path ~/gitlab/app_location/ --library ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_licensing/ \ --library ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/
```

and I got this error

```
Error: Argument '~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/' is not recognized.
```

So I removed the `market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/` line from the command, intending to take care of it later. The the error came back with

```
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
```

Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.

So I added `--target 21` to it and get

```
Resolved location of library project to: ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_licensing
```

Error: ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_licensing is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found).
Error: No Android Manifest at: ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/market_licensing

I've been working on this for about 3 days now and still have nothing to show for it. Is there something really obvious I'm doing wrong? I've never worked with expansion files before.